# Matplotlib transparent overlay & pdf transparency

Tags: python, matplotlib, overlay, imshow

Let's assume I have two numpy arrays (The ones I present are just examples):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(144).reshape((12, 12))
np.random.shuffle(A)

B = np.ones((12,12))
B[0:10:4,:] = None
```

I want to plot **A** using imshow:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplt
mplt.imshow(A, cmap = mplt.gray())
```

and overlay **B** so that the *None* areas are fully transparent and the *one* areas have an alpha of (e.g. alpha = 0.3.).

I already tried using something along the lines of:

```
mplt.imshow(B, cmap = mplt.get_cmap('Reds), alpha = 0.3)
```

but that does not work. Also tried to use masked arrays to create B, but cannot get my head around it. Any suggestions?

Thanks

## **EDIT:**

I ended up using

```
my_red_cmap = mplt.cm.Reds
my_red_cmap.set_under(color="white", alpha="0")
```

which works like a charm (I tested Bill's solution as well, which also works perfectly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If instead of `None` you use 0's for the transparent colors, you can take your favorite matplotlib colormap and add a transparent color at the beginning of it:

```py
my_red_cmap = mplt.cm.Reds
my_red_cmap.set_under(color="white", alpha="0")
```

then you can just plot the array `B` with a global alpha of 0.3 whatever you want, using your custom color map, which will use a transparent white as its first value.

Comment: Great, THanks! That is perfect and just what I needed! Now I just have a problem, the transparency shows when I display using "mplt.show()" but not when I use savefig to save it as a pdf... any idea why that happens?

Comment: When saving pdf's you must specify whether you want to preserve transparency, using something like `f.savefig('mygraph.pdf',  transparent=True)`

Comment: Unfortunately, even when using the "transparent" keyword, I still do not get transparency on the pdf :(

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10)
y = np.arange(-50, 150, 2).reshape(10, 10)
y[y<x] = -100 # Set bad values

cmap1 = cm.gray
cmap2 = cm.Reds
cmap2.set_under((1, 1, 1, 0))

params = {'interpolation': 'nearest'}
plt.imshow(x, cmap=cmap1, **params)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
plt.imshow(y, cmap=cmap2, **params)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
plt.imshow(x, cmap=cmap1, **params)
plt.imshow(y, cmap=cmap2, vmin=0, **params) # vmin > -100
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solution does what I wanted and partially solves the issue I have with the transparency when saving to pdf. The covered areas are not transparent, but the background shows where the bad values are.